# Insert image with relative path to the postgres table

Tags: postgresql

I have created following table in postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('test_id_seq'::regclass),
    file_content oid,
    name bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.test
    OWNER to postgres;
```

To put some example data via sql script:

```
INSERT INTO public.test(id, file_content, name) VALUES (1, lo_import('test.jpg'), 14);
```

It works fine when I am putting full path to binary file, like:
C:\temp\myTest\test.jpg
However if I am putting just filename (sql script exists in the same directory) then I am getting error that file does not exists.

Do you know if it is possible to execute lo_import with relative path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses `PGDATA` by default. We can see this using [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx):

[image]

You'll have to explicitly set a path if you require otherwise.

Comment: Do you know if there's any other way to load image (or just file) to the database by relative path?

Comment: Why do you need to?

Comment: I want to set up database with some data (like users, images, etc.). These data will be commited to the repository. All developers during building application will load these data (from repository) on their local databases. I would like to load these sample data, no matter what is the full path of the binary file.

Comment: You'll want to write a script that passes the path in as a variable then prefixes the file name with it